# How do I write a Photoshop Extension (8BX) plugin?

Tags: photoshop, photoshop-sdk

The Adobe Photoshop CS3/4 SDK has a lot of examples for Filter, Import, Export, etc plugins but I haven't found anything that illustrates how to write a 8BX plugin.

The reason is, I need to write one is to add a new drop-down menu to the Photoshop root toolbar (where it displays File, Edit, Image ... Window. Help drop-down menus). I have seen a product like OneSoftware install an 8BX plugin into Adobe Photoshop CS3\Plug-Ins\Extensions directory that causes PS to add adrop down menu for OneSoft. That suggests this is a solvable problem :-)

I tried by changing an existing plugin in the SDK samples but no go. Specifically I modified the resource file:

```
resource 'PiPL' (ResourceID, plugInName " PiPL", purgeable)
{
 {
  Kind { **Extension** },
  Name { plugInName "..." },
...
```

Despite using the Extension Kind, PS never loads the plugin. It doesn't generate any compile-time or load error either.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to go about doing this?

Comment: Old question, but it appeared in my search results. So if anyone is looking for the latest info on developing Photoshop plugins, check this link: https://www.adobe.io/photoshop/